# Calendar overlay issue with vanity URLS

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calendar, url

I have a sharepoint 2010 site with two vanity URLs  http://x.com and http://y.com

On the site i have a calendar with overlays to make things all colorful.  When i access the calendar by http://x.com/Lists/MyCalendar/calendar.aspx...the overlays show up fine.

However....if i access the calendar by http://y.com/Lists/MyCalendar/calendar.aspx the overlays are gone and there is a little error at the top saying "Unable to find specified web in the given URL - http://x.com.(.....) .  I don't understand why since it is the same sharepoint site.  I did read that this might be an issue with calendar overlays but i'm not sure how to handle it....Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define http://y.com as the primary URL for one of the other zones for that web application in Alternate Access Mappings.  It sounds like y.com is currently listed (if at all) as an AAM for x.com